# Generar un diccionario desde los modelos

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en Django y tengo 5 modelos:

- Empresa
- Agente
- Sensore
- Plantilla
- Datos

Hay varias relaciones como fijas en código. Lo que quiero es generar un  diccionario como este ejemplo en las Vistas:

```
{
  "Empresa": {
    "Agente": {
      "Memory": [
        {
          "plantia1":"Datos",
          "plantia2":"Datos"
        },
        {
          "plantia1":"Datos",
          "plantia2":"Datos"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

La verdad no sé cómo hacerlo. Éste es mi código:

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=600)
   tag = models.CharField(unique=True,blank=False,null=False, max_length=60)
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.Name

class Agente(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=600)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)
    referencia = models.CharField(unique=True,null=False,blank=False,max_length=600)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=False)
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.Name
class Sensore(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=150,unique=True)
    homepage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.Name
class Plantilla(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=150,unique=True)
   homepage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.Name
class Dato(models.Model):
   Datos = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=600)
   Plantillas = models.ForeignKey(Plantilla)
   Agente = models.ForeignKey(Agente)
   sensores = models.ForeignKey(Sensore)
   def agente(self):
      return self.Agente.Name
```

Comment: Hola Jamal, ¿qué versión de Python estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un módulo para Django que se llama `django-rest-framework` que incluye un paquete que ayuda a serializar modelos y sus relaciones en formato JSON, por ejemplo:

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

Te dejo un enlace con la documentación de los serializadores de modelos del paquete que te mencioné, ahí viene más detallada la información para trabajar con tus modelos y las relaciones que tengan con otros.

[Serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Saludos!